# Error when compiling: 'Vcl.forms.dcu' not found

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-10-seattle

I worked on my school IT project from home, on a newer Delphi (RAD Studio 10 Seattle). Now when I copied my program to work on it at school (Delphi 2010), it got an error when compiling *Vcl.Forms.Dcu not found*.

I have looked at other StackOverflow questions and my *Unit Output Library* is correctly set to `$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Dcp`, so I do not know what is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The `VCL` unit prefixing was added in XE2 to differentiate between same-named units in the VCL and (newly added) FMX frameworks.  Removing the `Vcl.` prefix will correct the error.

Comment: It was the complete opposite for me, with `Graphics` at least. Adding `Vcl.` fixed it.

Comment: @JerryDodge He's going *from* D10 *to* D2010, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

[Unit Scope Names](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Unit_Scope_Names) were introduced in XE2, so the `Vcl.Forms` unit does not exist in Delphi 2010, it was still known as `Forms` instead.

The correct solution in this situation is to refer to the `Forms` unit in your code as simply `Forms`, not as `Vcl.Forms`.  In your Seattle project options, make sure that `Vcl` is listed in the compiler's **Unit scope names** configuation field.

This way, when compiling the code, D2010 will look for `Forms.dcu` only, and Seattle will look for `Vcl.Forms.dcu` when it cannot find `Forms.dcu`.